# Binding mediator (shortbus) with/to ninject

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am trying to use the mediator pattern with shortbus(https://github.com/mhinze/ShortBus). Everything goes great except binding it to ninject. There is a structuremap example like so

```
    public BasicExample()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(i =>
        {
            i.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.AssemblyContainingType<IMediator>();
                s.TheCallingAssembly();
                s.WithDefaultConventions();
                s.AddAllTypesOf((typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)));
                s.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));
            });

            i.For<IDependencyResolver>().Use(() => DependencyResolver.Current);
        });

        ShortBus.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container));
    }
```

The above is for a unit test. I want to be able to unit test as well but most of all I just want it to work with the whole project.

There is a NinjectDependencyResolver and this should work with ninject. I just know ninject to poorly to get it straight.

I use Ninject MVC with NinjectWebCommon.
And the above code is supposed to work for structuremap so i simply need the equivalent for Ninject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninject works a bit differently.
For the `IRequestHandler<,>` and `INotificationHandler<>` type bindings you should use [ninject.extensions.conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) and do something like:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFromAny(
        new[]
        {
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
            typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
        })
    .BindDefaultInterfaces());

kernel.Bind<IDependencyResolver>().ToMethod(x => DependencyResolver.Current);


ShortBus.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

You may need to adapt the following:

- `FromThisAssembly()` --> this means only types of the assembly where you write that line will be bound. You can use another mechanism where you specify in which assemblies to look for your `ICommandHandler<>` and `IQueryHandler<,>` types.
- `BindDefaultInterfaces()`: See [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Projecting-Services-to-Bind) for an explanation and alternatives.

Also note that my example code is based upon [ShortBus.Ninject 3.0.48-Beta](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ShortBus.Ninject/3.0.48-beta). The most current ShortBus *stable* version is referencing StructureMap.

EDIT: I see that you tagged your question `asp.net`. Instead of using `StructureMap.Ninject` and it's `NinjectDependencyResolver` you are probably better off using [Ninject.Web.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/) (make sure it's the latest version!) and `NinjectDependencyResolver` of [Ninject.web.mvc](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc).

Comment: I don't qutie understand yrou Edit. I have Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Web.Mvc included in my references. I only use Ninject via the public static class NinjectWebCommon  in App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs. Did i misunderstand something?

Comment: it's just that the ShortBus.Ninject basically only provides another implementation of `NinjectDependencyResolver` - i guess for cases where you're not running in a web environment. So you don't actually need the `ShortBus.Ninject` package but just `ShortBus` (newest beta). I also would have though that with ninject.web.mvc you don't need to do `Bind<IDependencyResolver>` and `ShortBus.DependencyResolver.SetResolver` would need to to be adapted in case one uses ninject `IContext` (p.Ex. ContextPreservation extension) dependent features of ninject.

Comment: Do you have a complete solution?  I've been struggling to a) get the bind to recognise the inheritedfromany call, and b) get a better understanding of how this is supposed to work!

Comment: @TwistedInferno You mean a demo project with shortbus & ninject running? Or what's missing exactly?

Comment: Yes, a demo project would be ace.  I added the shortbus and ninject nuget packages but there was a problem with the inheritedfromany line, adding that line caused the compiler to no longer recognise the bind method and I receive a compile error 'cannot convert lambda expression to type system.type because it is not a delegate type'.  I'm open to it being something simple...

Comment: most likely an issue with brackets... `.InheritedFromAny` takes `Type[]` array as argument. The above example should compile - or doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness... don't forget to bind your IMediator

```
kernel.Bind<IMediator>().To<Mediator>();
```

Also worth noting that if you use BindDefaultInterfaces() you cannot name your handlers however you fancy. See link posted by BatteryBackupUnit.