# Is Service Locator an anti pattern in a pluggable architecture?

Tags: c#, plugins, dependency-injection, cqrs, service-locator

I know this question might look like it's a duplicate but please let me explain.

So I created several components that use a pluggable architecture, basically I can freely add new implementations and they will be injected and processed automatically for me. This is really handy in several scenarios.

I'm going to talk about the simplest one, validating components.

One of the reasons to use a design like this is that I like to expose my roles explicitly as explained by [Udi Dahan](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Making-Roles-Explicit-Udi-Dahan)

Basically I have code like this:

```
public interface IValidatorRuner
{
    void Run<TTarget>(TTarget target);
}

public class ValidatorRunenr : IValidatorRuner
{
    private readonly IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;

    public ValidatorRunenr(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    public void Run<TTarget>(TTarget target)
    {
        // this is the dynamic/pluggable phase
        // is this an antipattern???
        var foundValdiators = _serviceLocator.GetAllInstances<IValidator<TTarget>>();

        foreach (var valdiator in foundValdiators)
        {
            valdiator.IsSatisfiedBy(target);
        }
    }
}
```

This code lets me expose my validation rules explicitly like this:

```
//this will allow me to create validators in this way
//and they will be automatically injected and resolved for me 
//(easy, to read, easy to write, easy to test, pff I could even smoke this validator easily)
public class OneValdiationRuleExplicitlyExposedAndEasyToTest : IValidator<Person>
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Person target)
    {
        return target.Age > 18;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidator<TTarget>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(TTarget target);
}
```

And I will use this code like this:

```
//usage
public class SomeCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IValidatorRuner _validatorRuner;

    public SomeCommandHandler(IValidatorRuner validatorRuner)
    {
        _validatorRuner = validatorRuner;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _validatorRuner.Run(new Person{Age = 16});
    }
}
```

Validation was just one example, I also use it to fire domain events and to run pipelines and filters in the same pluggable way

Is using the service locator in this way an anti-pattern?

I know I might be hiding some dependencies, but the thing is that the dependencies are dynamically injected and discovered when the application initializes ([Composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/))

Your thoughts will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found a way to remove the ServiceLocator in my objects and still dynamically load/discover dependencies at run time.

The way I solved it was by registering my components in my DI container in the following way (using the Mediator pattern):
[Binding mediator (shortbus) with/to ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26206290/1268570)

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
.SelectAllClasses()
.InheritedFromAny(
    new[]
    {
        typeof(IValidatorRunner<>)
    })
.BindDefaultInterfaces());
```

And my final implementation looks like:

```
public interface IValidatorRuner<in TTarget>
{
    void Run(TTarget target);
}

public class ValidatorRunenr<TTarget> : IValidatorRuner<TTarget>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TTarget>> _validators;

    public ValidatorRunenr(IEnumerable<IValidator<TTarget>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public void Run(TTarget target)
    {
        foreach (var valdiator in _validators)
        {
            valdiator.IsSatisfiedBy(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
//usage
public class SomeCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IValidatorRuner<OneValdiationRuleExplicitlyExposedAndEasyToTest> _validatorRuner;

    public SomeCommandHandler(IValidatorRuner<OneValdiationRuleExplicitlyExposedAndEasyToTest> validatorRuner)
    {
        _validatorRuner = validatorRuner;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _validatorRuner.Run(new Person{Age = 16});
    }
}
```

In few words, by registering an opened generic type, my container resolves any call to that type creating a concrete-closed-generic-type instance at runtime for me.

As you can see *in the usage*, I do not have to create a specific concrete-closed-generic type of `IValidatorRunner<OneValdiationRuleExplicitlyExposedAndEasyToTest>` because the container creates one for me.

And there you go, now I'm happy because I removed the service locator from my domain objects =)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the primary issue with your code sample is that the service locator is itself injected into the implementation of ValidatorRunner. For me, this is an anti-pattern, but perhaps not the one you're asking about.

Any answer I might give boils down to the capabilities of your service locator implementation. But for sure it should not be passed into the constructor of your class. Instead, the service locator should itself pass these things in when you ask it for an implementation of "IValidatorRuner"

As an example, you can inject a factory that knows how to load the dynamic validator instances for a given type.

Comment: _you can inject a factory that knows how to load the dynamic validator instances_    My understanding of **"how to load the dynamic validator"** sounds like I'd be moving the service locator from the ValdiatorRunner to the factory right?